# Parse: query distinct locations with proximity filter

Tags: parse-platform

Is it possible to query distinct locations from Parse with certain proximity between locations, e.g. 50 miles. The point is I want to select the most liked locations but I want to discard less liked locations in proximity of more liked locations in order to diversify the result. I don't see the way to do that without slicing the whole world on rectangular areas and then feeding them to Parse.

Anyone had to solve that problem?

Comment: I keep reading, but with trouble understanding.  Can you post a functional question like: (my best guess after reading)  "I want to find well-liked (likes > 20) bowling alleys within 700 miles of my house, but I don't want to see any less-liked bowling alleys (likes < 10) that are within 50 miles of well-liked ones"

Comment: @danh I think you get it right. I want a world-wide rating of alleys but I don't want more than one alley in neighborhood to be there. Basically in order to make a room for other alleys from other places.

Comment: How about two highly rated alleys right next to each other?

Comment: @danh I just want one with most likes. So that's why I was talking about proximity, e.g. I can sort whole database by number of likes, but then I have to filter out results and narrow it down to maybe 10. So there are two levels of filters, first filters out alleys that are too close to each other, second pass can be offline and check distances between locations to get better results in sense of distribution on the map.

Comment: Gotcha - this is a very tough problem computationally.  Parse.com offers greaterThan some value to get places over some rating, and the most minimal nearness test.  Its not going to help you much.  Use the greaterThan test to get places in memory, then the rest is up to you -- you'll likely need to compute your own distance matrix between the results and filter in memory.  This is roughly an O(n^2) problem.

Comment: @danh that's why I was thinking to split the map on geo boxes and get the best spots within those boxes, this way I could drastically narrow down the amount of output. Then apply custom filter, cache results and refresh once a day. Roughly I could split the alleys by country or in case of large country – by state borders. Approximation is ok, no need in high precision.

Comment: Partitioning will surely reduce the size of the input to the computation but you'll need to develop the same computation to run on the smaller sets.  And the partition will generate error cases:  Consider two adjacent partitions, each containing one of a pair of two adjacent places.  Those two places might be very close neighbors, on each side of the partition boundary.  An algorithm that restricts itself to a partition will do the wrong thing with that pair.

Comment: You're right, but I guess this will be good enough for me as I use the coordinate of alley to fetch more from around later.